# How do I remove submodule schemes in an xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on a project that has a lot of dependencies, currently implemented as submodules. It seems that every submodule framework's target's schemes are automatically added to my parent project's scheme list, which is extremely bloated. I just want schemes for my project in particular listed. However, when I go to manage schemes and remove any of the submodules schemes, it's actually removing the scheme from the submodule, making it dirty. This is also the case for unchecking the "shared" option. Is there a way to remove (or hide) schemes for submodules in my parent project in a way that doesn't require removing schemes *within* the submodules themselves? I've thought about hiding them, but that only happens locally and are not reflected if other people are working on the project. I'd like them to be hidden (or removed) for all people if possible.

Answer (score -3):

```
git rm --cached moduleA
rm -rf moduleA
rm .gitmodules
vim .git/config

then remove this line like it 
[submodule "moduleA"]
      url = /Users/nick/dev/nick-doc/testGitSubmodule/moduleA.git

then Esc Exit the vim

git add .
git commit -m "remove submodule"


Done
```

Comment: Because the remote server relies on .gitmodules and moduleA for storage.
So I change this to resolve this problem.
I will be more detailed in the future. Thank you for your advice

Comment: The questions wasn't how to remove a submodule. It was how to remove/or hide a submodule's schemes from it's parent's Xcode project.